# $x^4-2x^3+x=y^4+3y^2+y$ in the set of integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

The task is to solve the equation $x^4-2x^3+x=y^4+3y^2+y$ in integers.

I expect is has something to do with factorizing but have no concrete idea; any help? thx guys

Comment: Have you been able to factorise both sides? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: First member factorizes as $x(x-1)(x^2-x-1)$ in irriducibles.

Comment: By observation, $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ are solutions.

Comment: Note that you can rearrange your original equation as
\begin{align}
(x^4-y^4) + (x-y) + 2(x^3-y^3) &= 3y^2+2y^3,
\end{align}
so that by factoring we have
\begin{align}
(x-y)(x+y-1)(x^2-x+y^2-y-1) &= y^2(2y+3).
\end{align}
Does this get you far enough to take it to the finish line?

Comment: Sorry, that first equation should have read $-2(x^3-y^3)$, not $+2$. The second factorization is still correct (_i.e._ as if the $+2$ was instead the correct $-2$.)

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem about inequalities, more than factorization.

**Step 1)** Prove that there exists a natural number $k$ such that $|x-y|>k$ implies that there are no solutions to the given equation;

**Step 2)** For any $j$ in the range $[-k,k]$, find the integer solutions to the cubic equation given by setting $y=x+j$;

**Step 3)** Profit. The only solutions are $(x,y)\in\{(0,0),(1,0),(3,2),(-2,2)\}$.